# How to strip out javascript in wp_posts `post_content`

Tags: filters

My website is undergoing an SQL injection attack redirecting to ad site dolohen[dot]com.

I need to strip out the javascript before it is served up.

**Is there a filter I can add or update to remove everything between   tags in wp_posts `post_content`**

I am new to programming wordpress but not to sql and databases.

Its a bit confusing because some people want to put javascript in posts but can't. Yet these SQL injectors seem to do it at will!

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript code is actually embedded in the post content, you *could* use php filters such as `the_content` to remove script tags. But that will strip it out at runtime, every time the page is loaded. If this is your situation, then you'd be better off stripping it out of the `wp_posts.post_content` table/column from the database.

If you want to quickly strip out the content *just for display*, you can use the `the_content` filter, like so (in your theme's functions file)

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){
    return wp_kses_post( $content );
});
```

But again, this will run *every time* the page is loaded. It's more of a short term fix.

Comment: Thanks Jake, how do I activate the 'the_content' php filter.

Comment: I am on my second iteration of cleaning out my posts manually but the javascript keeps coming back. When I query the database with phpmyadmin post come up with zero content??? Strange. One step at a time.

Comment: You aren't finding any script tags in post_content by searching with phpmyadmin?

Comment: (You may already know this, but )
To clean a hacked site, you have to look *everywhere*. I've found hacked htaccess, extra code in index files, bogus 'ico' files, and a hacked unused theme. Plus extra files that didn't belong there. 

To fix: change all credentials (hosting, database, admin/users), look at all folders for files that aren't supposed to be there (and look inside the ones that are there), update everything (PHP, WP, themes, plugins) from known good sources (manually), and more. 

Here's my cleanup notes: https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/

Comment: This is courtesy reply to Jake. Your answer started me off on a journey. I realised I had not got a clue what you had just told me and did not know what an add_filter was. Just to let you know, after a couple of weeks fairly intense reading on line and purchasing a few good WP/PHP/MySQL/Apache books and PHPDesigner8 I am have nearly understood your answer :-) In the meantime I have added a database trigger, before update which looks for scumbag script insertions and so far it's keeping these parasites at bay. I am developing a plugin to go on the attack against these people. Thanks to Rick too

Comment: Rick Hellewell: I am authoring a PDF Guide to SQL Injections in WordPress and will be releasing it once I have collated all the good advice, like yours, I have found during my search. Many thanks If you know or come across fixes or advice please mail me or post here. Thanks for a great start in getting after these b!%%&*(s